# This script wont sort correctly by age

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

My script asks for a name, phone number, and date of birth and then amends these details to a comma separated value file called “birthday.csv”.

It then Sorts “birthday.csv” by date of birth. The newly sorted file is then be displayed. It also calculates the age of each person and the number of entries in the file.

My problem is, it takes in all the information, but it then will not sort the file before printing the contents.

Here is the code:

```
a=0
while [ $a -lt 2 ];
do
    echo Please enter a first name
    read firstName
    echo Please enter last name
    read lastName
    echo Please enter phone number
    read phoneNumber
    echo Please enter date of birth - format dd/mm/yyyy
    read dob
    echo "$firstName,$lastName,$phoneNumber,$dob" >> Birthdays.csv
    echo If you would like to add another person press 1 or enter 2 to proceed
    read a
done

INPUT=./Birthdays.csv
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=","
[ -f ${INPUT} ] && while read Name Surname Telephone DOB
do
    birthMonth=${DOB:0:2}
    birthDay=${DOB:3:2}
    birthYear=${DOB:6:4}

    currentDate=`date +%d/%m/%Y`

    currentMonth=${currenDate:0:2}
    currentDay=${currentDate:3:2}
    currentYear=${currentDate:6:4}

    if [[ "$currentMonth" -lt "$birthMonth" ]] || [[ "$currentMonth" -eq "$birthMonth" && "$(currentDay)" -lt "$($birthDay)" ]]
    then
        let Age=currentYear-birthYear-1
    else
        let Age=currentYear-birthYear
    fi

    echo "Name : $Name"
    echo "Surname : $Surname"
    echo "Telephone : $Telephone"
    echo "DOB : $DOB"
    echo "Age : $Age"
    echo "##########################################"
done < $INPUT
IFS=$OLDIFS
    echo $DATE

exit 0;
```

I think the problem lies with

```
if [[ "$currentMonth" -lt "$birthMonth" ]] || [[ "$currentMonth" -eq "$birthMonth" && "$(currentDay)" -lt "$($birthDay)" ]]
then
    let Age=currentYear-birthYear-1
else
    let Age=currentYear-birthYear
fi
```

But I'm not sure what is causing that to not sort?

Comment: Where is the code that sorts?

Comment: I was hoping someone could give me some advice there, i am new to bash scripting and putting a sort code into this boggles my mind

Comment: can you use the `sort` utiltity, or are you deliberately trying to write code that controls and performs the sort? `sort -o newFile file` is the basics. Read `man sort` for some clues, or google host how use it, and then come back here with questions. Good luck.

Comment: @ChristianDiorHoward: then edit you question. It currently says the code you does a sort. But there's nothing in there that sorts anything, so it is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly remove the brackets around "$(currentDay)" and "$(currentDay)"

Answer (score 0):

One bug you have, at least:

```
if [[ "$currentMonth" -lt "$birthMonth" ]] || [[ "$currentMonth" -eq "$birthMonth" && "$(currentDay)" -lt "$($birthDay)" ]]
```

`"$(currentDay)"` should be just `"$currentDay"` and `"$($birthDay)"` should be just `"$birthDay"`.

You also have a typo here:

```
currentMonth=${currenDate:0:2}
```

That should be `currentDate`. Put `set -u` at the top of your script to catch such mistakes.

Also, like Mat said, I don't see any sorting code :)