# How to sort in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [This script wont sort correctly by age](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388467/this-script-wont-sort-correctly-by-age)

I have absolutaly no idea how to get this script to sort the info in Birthdays.csv by date of birth.
I know the sort -n command, however i wish to sort the file birthdays.csv by DOB. How would i go about doing this?

The below script gets user info and date of birth and then puts these info a file called “birthday.csv”.

I then need to Sort “birthdays.csv” by date of birth and then display this newly sorted information. I also calculate how old each person is by today's date. The problem i have is sorting the info in birthdays.csv by date of birth. Can someone let me know how i would do this sort?

The script is below:

```
a=0
while [ $a -lt 2 ];
do
    echo Please enter a first name
    read firstName
    echo Please enter last name
    read lastName
    echo Please enter phone number
    read phoneNumber
    echo Please enter date of birth - format dd/mm/yyyy
    read dob
    echo "$firstName,$lastName,$phoneNumber,$dob" >> Birthdays.csv
    echo If you would like to add another person press 1 or enter 2 to proceed
    read a
done

    INPUT=./Birthdays.csv
    OLDIFS=$IFS
    IFS=","
    [ -f ${INPUT} ] && while read Name Surname Telephone DOB
    do
                    birthMonth=${DOB:0:2}
                    birthDay=${DOB:3:2}
                    birthYear=${DOB:6:4}

                    currentDate=`date +%d/%m/%Y`

                    currentMonth=${currentDate:0:2}
                    currentDay=${currentDate:3:2}
                    currentYear=${currentDate:6:4}

                    if [[ "$currentMonth" -lt "$birthMonth" ]] || [[ "$currentMonth" -eq "$birthMonth" && "$currentDay" -lt "$$birthDay" ]]
                    then
                            let Age=currentYear-birthYear-1
                    else
                            let Age=currentYear-birthYear
                    fi

            echo "Name : $Name"
            echo "Surname : $Surname"
            echo "Telephone : $Telephone"
            echo "DOB : $DOB"
            echo "Age : $Age"
            echo "##########################################"
done < $INPUT
IFS=$OLDIFS
    echo $DATE

exit 0;
```

Comment: [man sort](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sort)

Comment: I understand how to sort, but i wish to sort the file by the Age of each person in the file. So really what i wish to know, is how do i sort a file by someone from within the file?

Comment: @ChristianDiorHoward you would be almost there with `-k, --key=KEYDEF` (using `-t,` for field separator), but with your choice of dd/mm/yyyy for date format, it becomes non-trivial.

Comment: Seems it takes a little magic with the flags... http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/52800-sort-csv-file.html  That forum discussion has a lot of info that may be relevant to your needs

Comment: it is not a duplicate, the script has since changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this line

```
sort -o $INPUT -n -t , -k4.7,4 -k4.4,4.5 -k4.1,4.2 $INPUT
```

After

```
INPUT=./Birthdays.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Try --  ### cat Birthdays.csv | sort --field-separator='/' --key=3,5